# Работа с папками через командную строку (создание папок и удаление папок)

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse, python-click

Написать проект, который можно будет использовать следующим образом:

```
python main.py create folder_name - создает папку folder_name, если она еще не создана. Если создана - выводит об этом сообщение
python main.py delete folder_name - удаляет папку folder_name, если она пуста. Если не пуста - выводит об этом сообщение
python main.py delete -f folder_name - удаляет папку folder_name вне зависимости от того, есть в ней файлы или нет.
```

Написал три разных программы:

```
# программа create_folder.py
import os
import argparse
def create():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('name')
    return parser
parser = create()
create = parser.parse_args()
if not os.path.isdir(create.name):
    os.mkdir(create.name)
else:
    print(f'Папка {create.name} уже существует')

#программа delete.py

import os
import argparse
def delete():
     parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
     parser.add_argument ('name')
     return parser
parser = delete()
delete = parser.parse_args()
try:
     os.rmdir(delete.name)
except:
     print(f"папка {delete.name} не пуста")


#программа fdelete.py

import shutil
import argparse
def fdelete():
     parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
     parser.add_argument ('name')
     return parser
parser = fdelete()
fdelete = parser.parse_args()

shutil.rmtree(fdelete.name)
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это объединить в один проект, что бы вызывать ту программу которая нужна по функции. И как функцию delete разделить на функцию delete и -f delete?
Сейчас программы работают если писать >python {название программы} [имя папки]

Comment: Ну просто добавьте все функции в один файл, а по пришедшим опциям выбирайте, что надо вызывать. В чём проблема?

Comment: @dIm0n это так не работает, по крайней мере, у меня не получалось

Comment: Вы бы привели неполучившуюся попытку, мы бы указали на ошибки в коде

Answer (score 0):

Решил эту задачу через click:

```
import click
import os
import shutil

@click.group()
def cli():
    pass

@click.command()
@click.argument('folder')
def create(folder):
    if not os.path.isdir(folder):
        os.mkdir(folder)
    else:
        print(f'Папка {folder} уже существует')


@click.command()
@click.argument('folder')
@click.option('-f', is_flag=True)
def delete(f,folder):
    if f:
        shutil.rmtree(folder)
    else:
        try:
             os.rmdir(folder)
        except:
             print(f"папка {folder} не пуста")


cli.add_command(create)
cli.add_command(delete)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cli()
```